# iOS Indoor Map For Shopping Mall / Any Building

Tags: ios, iphone, google-maps, mapkit, mapbox

I am new to iOS development, I am creating app for the exhibition area. For example suppose there is hall, which contains 200 exhibitors booth.Now I want to create App with Map for this exhibition area, where I can see all the booths with their information. user can search for booths as well as he can get direction to the particular booth.

For this I have floor plan image of the exhibition area.
I have searched a lot about indoor maps, but googles indoor map doesn't full fill my requirements.

The **"Indoor Navigation and Mapping Engine - Jibestream"** provides exact the same functionality which i am looking for. But **Jibestream** SDK is very expensive.

I searched but I am unable to find any alternative for the same.

I really appreciate if anyone provide me an alternate **framework** or any other solution to achieve this.
[Sample floor plan image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c5qoy.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I would say that what you want to achieve (indoor navigation) is not trivial. You can't use a regular map (Maps, Google Maps, etc) because you can't rely on the GPS indoor. You can place beacons around the exhibition area to position the users with triangulation and some calculations.

You could explore third party libraries for this like:

- [MapsPeople](https://www.mapspeople.com/)
- [Estimote](http://developer.estimote.com/indoor/)

Answer (score 1):

As Ruben Marin mentioned above, indoor positioning and navigation are both quite complicated features. There are several iBeacon vendors that have their SDK with indoor positioning feature implemented. Some of them use Fingerprinting method (like Estimote does) to calculate indoor position. Here are the main disadvantages of this method:

- additional work to create radio map
- need to update radio map on each environment changes
- not the best accuracy

On the other hand, there is another company (like [Leantegra](https://github.com/leantegra)) with indoor positioning solution that deploys Multilateration method, which has some advantages comparing to the previous one:

- decent accuracy
- no need of radio map
- stable deployment